# Use CASE WHEN statement with Sql

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I used this query

```
SELECT nvl(round(sum(PAP.QTY_PLAN_ANPLN) / 1000), 0) PRODUCTION  
FROM PPC_ANNUAL_PLANS PAP
WHERE PAP.MAAST_ASSET_ID IN( '35390','35392')
```

Replace `where` clause with this code

```
PAP.MAAST_ASSET_ID in (CASE   
        WHEN 'DRI' = 'RMP'
            THEN  '2242'

        WHEN 'DRI' = 'DRI'
            THEN  '35390,35392'

        WHEN 'DRI' = 'SMP'
            THEN  '2241'
   END)
```

Oracle throw this error

> ORA-01722: invalid number

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: `'35390,35392'` will be treated as a String and not as list of numbers as you expect. I assume the case statement if just for an example. As it is just a constant vs constant comparison...

Comment: The conditions of your case are constant - it will always pick the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

Use OR in the `where` condition, like this:

```
where 
 dri = 'DRI' AND MAAST_ASSET_ID in (200,300) 
OR
 dri = 'SMP' AND MAAST_ASSET_ID in (222,333)
OR
 dri = 'RMP' AND MAAST_ASSET_ID in (555,777,888)
```

if you insist on using CASE expressions, then it certainly can be done in this way:

```
where 
 1 = case
    when dri = 'DRI' AND MAAST_ASSET_ID in (200,300) THEN 1
    when dri = 'SMP' AND MAAST_ASSET_ID in (222,333) THEN 1
    when dri = 'RMP' AND MAAST_ASSET_ID in (555,777,888) THEN 1
END
```

but the second condition may kill your database performance for large tables ==> Oracle is able to optimize the first query, but can't do it for the second condition, and it will always use a full table scan on the table in this case.